# Retrieve certain value located in dataframe in any row or column and keep it in separate column without forloop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below

```
df              
    A           B            C  
    0           1            TRANSIT_1  
    TRANSIT_3           
    0           TRANSIT_5
```

And I want to change it to below:
Resulting DF

```
A   B   C   D
0   1       TRANSIT_1
            TRANSIT_3
0           TRANSIT_5
```

[image: img]

So i tried to use str.contains and once I receive the series with True or False, i put it in eval function to somehow get me the table I want.

Code I tried:

```
series_index = pd.DataFrame()
series_index = df.columns.str.contains("^TRANSIT_", case=True, regex=True)
print(type(series_index))
series_index.index[series_index].tolist()
```

## I thought to use eval function to write it to separate column,like

```
df = eval(df[result]=the index) # I dont know, But eval function does evaluation and puts it in a separate column
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a simple one-liner, but this works:

```
idx = list(df1[df1.where(df1.applymap(lambda x: 'TRA' in x if isinstance(x, str) else False)).notnull()].stack().index)
a, b = [], []
for sublist in idx:
    a.append(sublist[0])
    b.append(sublist[1])
df1['ans'] = df1.lookup(a,b)
```

#### Output

```
           A          B          C        ans
0          0          1  TRANSIT_1  TRANSIT_1
1  TRANSIT_3       None       None  TRANSIT_3
2          0  TRANSIT_5       None  TRANSIT_5
```

Comment: Thank you! That works for me.  I kind of modified it as required by me based on your code. It worked too!!

idx = list(df1[df1.where(df1.applymap(lambda x: 'TRA' in x if isinstance(x, str) else False)).notnull()].stack().index)
print(idx)
df1["ans"] = ''
for sublist in idx:
    df1.loc[sublist[0], "ans"] = df1.loc[sublist[0],sublist[1]]
    df1.loc[sublist[0], sublist[1]] = None

print(df1)